# Пустить весь трафик на сетевой интерфейс в линуксе

Tags: linux, iptables, socks5

Имеется сокс клиент вип72, запущенный из под wine, при работе этого клиента на адрес 127.0.0.1:9951 транслируется SOCKS5.

Вопрос - как весь этот трафик передать отдельному интерфейсу например eth9

Навеяло статьёй о пробросе трафика ТОР на отдельный интерфейс
https://cryptopunks.org/article/forward+all+the+traffic+to+tor/

Answer (score 3):

При помощи socat нужно склеить сокет 127.0.0.1:9951 и (адрес eth9):9951

Например, если у eth9 адрес 10.0.0.1/8

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9951,fork,range=10.0.0.1/8 TCP:127.0.0.1:9951
```

Либо при помощи iptables

Comment: а как это потом к интерфейсу привязать ?

Comment: По адресу. Если у eth9 будет адрес 10.0.0.1, команда будет иметь вид socat TCP-LISTEN:10.0.0.1:9951,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:9951

Comment: 2017/03/01 09:04:03 socat[8604] E TCP-LISTEN: wrong number of parameters (2 instead of 1)

Comment: Обновил ответ - исправил формат

Comment: 2017/03/01 09:13:20 socat[11093] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:9951}, 16): Address already in use

Comment: Тогда цепляйте на другой порт