# Можно ли перенаправить трафик tcp соединения при подключении к одному компьютеру по ssh туннелю до другого компьютера?

Tags: linux, ssh, jupyter-notebook

Если локальная сеть с двумя машинами на linux. Есть доступ к одной из них по ssh, к другой - нет. На машине, недоступной по ssh есть сервер (jupyter notebook). Можно ли подключиться по ssh к другой машине, и получить трафик с нее при подключении к jupyter?

Comment: Возможно вам нужен ключ -L или -R у ssh

Comment: да, но каким образом с компьютера с ssh установить подключение к компьютеру без ssh и перенаправить весь трафик?

Comment: Так ко второй машине нет доступа вообще или есть только с первой машины?

Comment: Хотя я что-то вообще перестал понимать какой трафик вы хотите получить

Comment: например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576

Comment: Ещё почти про то же: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633916/191416

Answer (score 2):

1. Создать туннель: `ssh user@ssh.host -Llocalhost:8080:jupyter.notebook:80`
2. Запросы к jupyter-сервису слать на localhost tcp-port 8080